# Spam Questions Increases

Tags: support, moderation

Patents is getting a bunch of Spam lately. Is there anyway we can get the moderator to delete them more rapidly? I and others are flagging as spam and downvoting.

Answer (score 2):

Ask Patents currently [has no moderators](https://patents.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators). The Stack Exchange company [was supposed to be moderating the site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/348367), but the staff member responsible for AP moderation, [Robert Catarino](https://patents.stackexchange.com/users/1), was [unexpectedly fired](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342039) in January.

Other sites in the Stack Exchange network are moderated by volunteers and host occasional [moderator elections](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135360). That might be an option here if your community has members who would be willing to commit to a moderation role.

In order to get more moderators, you'll have to contact Stack Exchange staff and ask them either to appoint a new employee moderator or to start a moderator election. The best way to get in touch with them is probably to post a question on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com) and [flag it for [status-review]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348642).

---

In the meantime, there is a user group called [Charcoal](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) which is focused on identifying and deleting spam content across the network. If you come across a spam post that hasn't been deleted, feel free to post a link in [our chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq). We'll gladly flag the post in order to help it reach the 6-flag threshold for deletion, and we can blacklist keywords/URLs/user accounts so that our [automated spam-detection systems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291301) can identify it quicker next time.

Comment: I might be willing to provide moderation of Ask Patents since it is a pretty low volume SE site and most everybody is well behaved. Do you know how I would make SE aware of this?

Comment: I think the best thing to do is probably to start a discussion on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com) explaining the siutation. It might also be worth hopping in the [Tavern on the Meta](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) chat room first to get a second opinion, since there are people there who would know better than me about what to do.